# Angular accessibility aria-live won't vocalize on "0" value

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, accessibility, aria-live

I'm willing to make an Angular component vocable for visual impairs.
The components has two buttons which add or remove 10 on the displayed value.
The displayed value is vocable for any value except when the value is "0%". I can't figure this out.

Software used to vocalize : NVDA latest on windows.

Working example : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stepper-input?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-input%2Fstepper-input.component.html

Ps : this has nothing to do with Angular afaik, same example with vanilla js presents the same issue.

Thanks

*UPDATE:
Firefox and Edge : Not working,
Chrome and IE : Working*

Comment: i couldn't get the stackblitz url to work on firefox but did on chrome.  in chrome, with nvda, 0% was read. here's what i heard after clicking + a few times then - to get to zero: "*Plus 10 button, 20%, 30%, Less 10 button, 20%, 10%, 0%, Plus 10 button, 10%, Less 10 button, 0%*"

Comment: Thanks for testint. Means that there must be a problem with my NVDA maybe...

Comment: I’m using the default settings for nvda. What browser did you use?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: I updated with the working and not working browsers.